# Remove filter property of a div in css using firefox

Tags: javascript, css, svg, svg-filters

I was trying to remove the property "filter" of one of my div that I apply on my all body, but all things I have done doesn't work.

I made a fiddle to show the thing: **http://jsfiddle.net/fAmu4/1/**

I want that the blue div have not blur on it when the cursor is on it.

I tried the "filter: none;" but it doesn't work. I also tried to apply a new blur:

```
<filter id="remove-blur">
   <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="0" />
</filter>
```

which don't work too.

I watched also on the internet about that, but no way to find a solution. 
It's important to notice that my code only work in firefox.

Thank's in advance !

Edit:

**Working fiddle: *http://jsfiddle.net/fAmu4/5/***

Comment: updated with other 2 fiddle, please, let me know

Comment: If you have a filter on a parent then all children are always filtered. That's just the way filters work.

Comment: @RobertLongson I see. I notice that in my website, I got a div that contains all the elements that I want to blur. I gonna try to blur only that div and see what happen, thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Like previous post. And you can add a class tag "=blur" to every div you want to apply the effect on and target that.
Or use only "div" as target to effect all, and then give the div you want to show a class or id that you can target to unblur it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this helps:([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/829uF/15/))

**style**

```
body.blur {
    filter:url(#blur-effect);
}

#haut{
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

#bas{
    background-color: darkred;
}
#bas2{
    background-color: red;
}
```

**html**

```
<div id="haut" onmouseover="flou();" onmouseout="flou();">
    test
</div>

<div id="bas">
    test
</div>

<svg>
   <filter id="blur-effect">
       <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5" />
   </filter>
</svg>

<div id="bas2">
    test
</div>
```

**JS**

```
 function flou() {
        b = document.body;
        c = b.className;
        if (c.indexOf('blur') > 0) {//when blur is active
            b.className = ""
    //remove blur
        } else {
            b.className += ' blur'; //apply blur
        }
    }
document.getElementById('haut').onmouseover=function(){document.body.className="";}
```

or something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/829uF/18/)
or [this](http://jsfiddle.net/fAmu4/3/)

Comment: It's not what I want sorry! I want to blur all div except one, but I don't think we can do this that way.

Thanks for your answer

Comment: @Off I don't understand what do you exactly need but I can suggest you to target the element you want to blur and then, control that elements with js

Comment: Yes sorry my english is very bad. I am actually doing what you suggest, I would post a fiddle of it if it works, I thing it gonna work.

Comment: @Off Not for your english, sometimes it's not easy to explain a visual effect just with words. Gl